# Should I be accessing protected methods for unit tests?

Tags: c#, unit-testing, visual-studio-2008

In relation to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15197141/how-to-properly-test-an-abstract-class) I asked earlier, I am stuck yet again with my unit test.

My current problem is in relation to testing the `protected` methods of my abstract `Component` class.

I've successfully implemented a mock class, named `ConcreteComponent`, which does its job very well of inheriting everything the abstract class has.

Thing is, I made this concrete class inside my unit test file. The only way of testing protected methods is to have a Private Accessor. However, I cannot create a Private Accessor inside the same file as where the unit test is, and thus, cannot access the protected methods.

I've tried to place the mock concrete class in a separate file, under a different namespace, and this now allows me to create a Private Accessor to which the unit test file can now use. It worked nicely, but then I figured I need this mock concrete class inside the same file where the unit test is.

So now I have two questions:

1) What are the possible workarounds for this problem?

2) Why can't I create a private accessor for a mock class which is inside the same file and namespace as the unit test class?

Comment: "Why can't you" is a great question. Why can't you? What exactly is happening or preventing you?

Comment: well VS2008 won't allow me, for whatever reason that is. When the class is in the same file as the unit test, there are no options to create a Private Accessor when I right-click on the mock class' name. But when I place the mock class in a separate file, the option to create a Private Accessor appears.

Comment: Ahhh, so it' the IDE not letting you. Didn't realise you were using MSTEST and auto-generating accessors. In that case I'd follow Saurabh's advice below and trust/ensure that either the public interface is exercising the protected code or, if it's not, why does it even matter if it's broken?

Answer (score 2):

You can take a look at [PrivateObject](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms245564.aspx) class to gain access to non-public API of your class in your tests. It uses reflection internally. Protected assets of a class are still api to an external client which in this case is a sub or derived class. So desire to test such api is understandable. I would not recommend polluting a class to expose public api just for the sake of testing protected api. However, since in your case the derived class is in a test project, you can actually provide public api to make testing easier and improve the performance (reflection will be slower and if you are running tests, continuous testing, as you make code changes, it may make test runs slower depending on the number of test etc.).

Comment: +1 for reference to the PrivateObject class.  Although the top rated answer is good, I am surprised that this hasn't been upvoted!

Comment: You sir, have just changed my life!

Answer (score 0):

Protected functionality is there because you do not want to expose it to your client. But If it is protected then may be accessed through the public interface via some satisfying condition if it is not then it is a dead code so remove it.

so the golden rule is

1- Do not try to circumvent testing private / protected methods by using technology (Reflection etc), try to unit test private / protected through the public interface and BTW why your are using VS 2008 Test and why not NUnit instead

Comment: I'd add to this, refactor that functionality out to other classe(s) so it can be unit tested by itself

Comment: Seconded; either the private methods should be tested indirectly through the public interface, or they are complicated enough that they should be extracted out into a new class.

Comment: for proteced methods, your "client" could be a class than derives from the base calss and therefore could access its protectred methods. Protected methods are part of the consumable interface of your object. completely agree with your point though if you are talking about private methods rather than protected ones.

Comment: even though protected methods is inherited but can not used directly  by the consumer of inherited class , it must be accessed through the public interface which you publish so must be tested through that only

Comment: @Saurabh: so how do you test your code if you're a framework developer and you don't have any inherited classes in your framework? The clients of your framework are supposed to derive from your classes and use your protected api and you still want that protected api to work and be able to unit test right?

Comment: if i do not have inherited classes so why shd i have protected methods in my framework , i think you mean Virtual methods if i want my client to override functionality of a class. But just giving protected methods in the framework does not sounds right to me. If i use protected in than i intended to have inherited classes with in my framework.

Comment: but I do have a class that inherits from the abstract class which contains the protected methods. So what workaround should I really do? Just in case the point I made in my question above isn't clear enough, my abstract class, which is named `Component`, is the one that contains the protected methods. I created a mock class, `ConcreteComponent` which inherits from the abstract class.

Comment: @Saurabh: Your framework may or may not provide inherited classes. You are providing a framework for others to build on right? Sure your base class can have virtual methods that allow derived classes to add their own specialization. I can give you a base BankAccount class with protected MoneyTransfer method that handles the rules and the mechanics of the money transfer and provides also a virtual Transfer method that derive classes override. You can inherit from the base class and write savings or checking account classes in your library.