# how to access private members of an abstract class

Tags: c#, unit-testing, abstract-class

In relation to my other thread about testing abstract classes (which can be found [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15200768/should-i-be-accessing-protected-methods-for-unit-tests)), my problem now is accessing the private variables of an abstract class. This has something to do with using a `Private Accessor`, but as I have stated in the other thread, I can't create a private accessor inside the same file as the unit test.

Here are the private variables I'm talking about:

```
public abstract class Component {

    private eVtCompId mComponentId;   //enum
    private eLayer mLayerId;   //enum
    private IF_SystemMessageHandler mLogger;    //interface
```

I need to know how to access these, because I'm creating a unit tests that involves getting the value inside these particular variables.

Comment: You shouldn't test the state of an object via unit tests. The only acceptable way of interaction for unit tests is invoking methods.

Comment: Internal implementation of a class shouldn't be the subject of a unit test.  In theory, the way this class "works" can change and shouldn't cause a unit test to fail, only the public consumable results/properties of the class should remain consistent.

Comment: Now that you are planning to work against the OO principles. If you really want to access these variables create a protected function or a property that returns the value of these variables and access it in the derived class.

Comment: @PSCoder: they are private

Answer (score 1):

You would need to use reflection

```
var instance = new Component();
...
var fieldInfo = typeof(Component).GetField("mComponentId", BindingFlags.Instance | BindingFlags.NonPublic);
var componentId = (eVtCompId)fieldInfo.GetValue(instance);
```

Answer (score 1):

If you don't mind being a bit ugly, you can define functions that will only be compiled when you are compiling in Debug mode by doing:

```
#if DEBUG
            ...
#endif
```

Then you can define methods that are public and simply return what the value of a private variable is, such that they are only accessible for unit testing.