# How to perform Moq testing for abstract class in C# for virtual methods inside it?

Tags: c#, moq

I would like to perform testing for below abstract `Streaming` class which has two virtual methods that are overridden in the `Asset` class in same project. Here the `SerializeBinary()` method converts an object into binary streams and `DeserializeFromBinary()` method does the opposite of `SerializeBinary()`.

How to write test class for comparing both using Moq?

I go through from [here:](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15197141/how-to-properly-test-an-abstract-class)

This is part of my code:

`Streaming` class:

```
public abstract class Streaming
{
        private static int _streamingIDExponent = 41;
        public const string MonthLookup = "ABCDEFGHIJK";
        public const string ExpiryStringFormat = "ddMMMyyyy";
        public const double DefaultTicksPerPoint = 3;
        private long _StreamingID;
        private int _minQty = DefaultMinimumQty;

        public virtual void SerializeBinary(BinaryStreamWriter binaryStreamWriter)
        {
                 binaryStreamWriter.Write(_StreamingID);
                 binaryStreamWriter.Write(_ex_StreamingID);
                 binaryStreamWriter.Write(_minQty);
                 binaryStreamWriter.Write(_extendedProperties.Count);

                 foreach (KeyValuePair<StreamingPropertyName, StreamingProperty> dictionaryEntry in _extendedProperties)
                 {
                     dictionaryEntry.Value.SerializeBinary(binaryStreamWriter);
                 }
}

public virtual bool DeserializeFromBinary(BinaryStreamReader binaryStreamReader, out string errorString)
{
         errorString = string.Empty;

         try
         {
               _StreamingID = binaryStreamReader.ReadInt64();
               _exStreamingID = binaryStreamReader.ReadInt64();
               _minQty = binaryStreamReader.ReadInt32();    
         }
         catch (Exception oEx)
         {
               errorString = oEx.Message;
         }

         return string.IsNullOrEmpty(errorString);
}
```

`Asset` class:

```
public class Asset : Streaming
{
    public override void SerializeBinary(BinaryStreamWriter binaryStreamWriter)
    {
        base.SerializeBinary(binaryStreamWriter);
    }

    public override bool DeserializeFromBinary(BinaryStreamReader binaryStreamReader, out string errorString)
    {
            if (!base.DeserializeFromBinary(binaryStreamReader, out errorString))
                   return false;

            try
            {
                  return true;
            }
            catch (Exception oEx)
            {
                 errorString = oEx.Message;
                 return false;
            }
     }
 }
```

Comment: Do you want to test the `Streaming` class's functionality, the `Asset` class's functionality, or the `Asset` class's interaction with the base `Streaming` class?

Comment: What makes this different to the similar unclear question you asked previously http://stackoverflow.com/questions/42456607/how-to-perform-nunit-testing-in-a-project-on-class-level

Comment: @wablab  I want to test the Streaming class's functionality. How to proceed?
Kindly suggest.

Comment: `var target = new Mock<Streaming>();` then `target.CallBase = true;`

Comment: @wablab  How to test the `Asset` class's interaction with the base `streaming` class?

Comment: @AnkitRaman, I posted an answer below that shows an example of how to test the interaction of `Asset` with `Streaming`.  It's not a perfect solution, but it's about as good as it gets with Moq.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's no good way to test the interaction between `Asset` and `Streaming` with Moq in your current implementation.  However, if you're willing to change the implementation of the classes just a bit, you can get it done.  Basically, you'll want to move the logic of the `Streaming` class's methods into new methods, and you can then mock those.

```
public abstract class Streaming
{
    public virtual void SerializeBinaryCore(BinaryStreamWriter writer)
    {
        // put the logic from your original SerializeBinary method here...
    }

    public virtual bool DeserializeFromBinaryCore(BinaryStreamReader reader, out string errorMessage)
    {
        // put the logic from your original DeserializeFromBinary method here...
    }

    public abstract void SerializeBinary(BinaryStreamWriter writer);

    public abstract bool DeserializeFromBinary(BinaryStreamReader reader, out string errorMessage);
}
```

And then tweak your `Asset` class as follows:

```
public class Asset : Streaming
{
    public override void SerializeBinary(BinaryStreamWriter writer)
    {
        SerializeBinaryCore(writer);
    }
    public override void DeserializeFromBinary(BinaryStreamReader reader, out string errorMessage)
    {
        var result = DeserializeFromBinaryCore(reader, out errorMessage);
        // put the rest of your Asset deserialization logic here...
    }
}
```

In your test, you need to create a `Mock<Asset> { CallBase = true }`, and then create setups for the `SerializeBinaryCore` and `DeserializeFromBinaryCore` methods.

Comment: Your Idea puted me in comfort zone.now I successfully did it.thank you so much.

Comment: I have one more query like I have to define a benchmark for `SerializeBinary(BinaryStreamWriter writer)` and `DeserializeFromBinary(BinaryStreamReader reader, out string errorMessage)` so that it would not take more time than 0.09 ms.
And also to find if we run these two methods in a loop and if this loop iterate till 5000 then how much time it will take? How to test it?

Kindly help if possible.

Comment: @AnkitRaman, performance testing is a completely separate question that others could probably answer better than I could.  I'd recommend you ask a separate question for this.  To get you started, however, you might want to look at the `System.Diagnostics.Stopwatch` class.  It is based on the PC's high-resolution timer, so you can get fairly accurate timestamps for your measurements.  Also keep in mind that sometimes the first execution of your method (in a loop, for example) will be significantly slower than subsequent executions due to JIT'ing.

Comment: Thank you. I did it by using `System.Diagnostics.Stopwatch` class.

Comment: Yes,I did it by using `Stopwatch` class.Here I have puted my methods in try catch block and it is properly work for known test cases results and Exceptions, but here my requirement is like It should have to work for unhandled Exceptions.
what should I do?
for example: `Assert.IsInstanceOf(typeof(Streaming), asset," Type is not same.");`where `asset` is instance of `Asset` class. it works fine. but how for unhandled exceptions?

Answer (score 2):

you can create a new Mock of your Streaming class like this:

```
var streamingMock = new Mock<Streaming> { CallBase = true };
```

The call base is important because it will then execute the implemented code in your concrete class.
Then you can call the methods via the Object property:

```
streamingMock.Object.SerializeBinary(...);
```

Hope this helps

Comment: How to test the `Asset` class's interaction with the base `streaming` class?

Comment: As your `Asset` derives from the concrete `Streaming` class, there is to my knowledge no possibility to "mock" it. So if you need to test if your `base` is called then you really need to test the concrete implementation of `Streaming`.

Comment: I have one more query like I have to define a benchmark for `SerializeBinary(BinaryStreamWriter writer)` and `DeserializeFromBinary(BinaryStreamReader reader, out string errorMessage)` so that it would not take more time than 0.09 ms.
And also to find if we run these two methods in a loop and if this loop iterate till 5000 then how much time it will take?

Kindly help if possible.

Comment: Hi Ankit
in order to measure time that the execution took you can do the following:
`var watch = System.Diagnostics.Stopwatch.StartNew();`
`// the code that you want to measure comes here`
`watch.Stop();`
`var elapsedMs = watch.ElapsedMilliseconds;`

But i would not make a test that fails if the performance is not as expected, as this really depends on the system the tests are run on, so you really need to be careful there...

Comment: Yes,I did it by using `Stopwatch` class.Here I have puted my methods in try catch block and it is properly work for known test cases results and Exceptions, but here my requirement is like It should have to work for unhandled Exceptions.
what should I do?
for example: `Assert.IsInstanceOf(typeof(Streaming), asset," Type is not same.");`where `asset` is instance of `Asset` class. it works fine. but how for unhandled exceptions?